# Object literals concatenate string attributes

Tags: javascript

I'm using Javascript Object literals , but i can't concatenate string attributes.

```
var cart  = {
baseURL   : "http://www.domain.com/",
addURL    : this.baseURL + "cart/add",
deleteURL : this.baseURL + "cart/delete",
totalURL  : this.baseURL + "cart/total",
// functions
}// cart
```

i get a link as `http://www.domain.com/undefinedcart/add`

Please any help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe `this.baseURL` is undefined?

Comment: @Christoph: I didn't see second line. you are right. error has nothing common with posted code.

Comment: All works fine just to getting correct url.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have access to the `baseURL` in that way. Thats because `this` is actually `window` and it probably does not has property `baseURL`.

You can use Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ([IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) and closure instead:

```
var cart = function () {
   var baseURL = "http://www.domain.com/";
   return {
      addURL    : baseURL + "cart/add",
      deleteURL : baseURL + "cart/delete",
      totalURL  : baseURL + "cart/total"
   };
}();
```

Comment: In your second approach`cart` is not yet assigned therefore its still undefined, also an IIFE is quite unnecessary.

Comment: It's necessary because you save the environment from globals :). Thank you for your first note.

Comment: In the interest of readability, I like wrapping IIFEs in parens: `(function () {...}())` so it's immediately clear that it's an expression.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't concatenation within the context of the object, it's that the **this** you're looking for doesn't exist yet. A simple solution might look like *this*:

```
var baseURL = "http://www.domain.com/";
var cart  = {
baseURL   : baseURL,
addURL    : baseURL + "cart/add",
deleteURL : baseURL + "cart/delete",
totalURL  : baseURL + "cart/total",
}
```

Or this:

```
var cart = new function() {
  this.baseURL = "http://www.domain.com/";
  this.addURL = this.baseURL + "cart/add";
  this.deleteURL = this.baseURL + "cart/delete";
  this.totalURL = this.baseURL + "cart/total";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable "this" is a instance of Window, so you can't use "this" as "cart"

Comment: I solved it, so the solution was the make `baseURL"` out of cart and   i changed 'this` to `cart` :

    var baseURL   = "http://www.domain.com/";

    var cart  = {
    addURL    : baseURL + "cart/add",
    deleteURL : baseURL + "cart/delete",
    totalURL  : baseURL + "cart/total",
    add : function(){
       value = cart.addURL // example to call cart attributes
     },
     
    }// cart